# Django download files errors "zip file is invalid"

Tags: python, django, file, web-applications

Here is my view code to download a file

```
def download_order(request,order_id):
      purchase=GigPurchase.objects.select_related().get(order_id=order_id)
      order=purchase.order  
      wrapper=FileWrapper(open(order.path,"rb")) 
      content=mimetypes.guess_type(order.path)[0]
      t=purchase.gig.title
      title=slugify(t)
      response=HttpResponse(wrapper,content_type=content)
      response['Content-Disposition']='attachment;filename=%s.zip'%(title)
      return response
```

I have a model that has a file field named "order". What am i doing wrong here because when I click on the link. I get the download file but when I try to open it I get "The compressed zip folder is invalid". Please help. Thanks

Comment: I don't see the part where you create the zip file, did you forget to include it?

Comment: sorry for the late response. I am copying examples that I've seen online and this was how i saw it. How do i go about creating the zip file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should understand that this code only sends the file from `order.path`, you need to create that file in your code. Regarding creating zip files you can start with the stdlib [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile) module.